# SQL Server Grouped results containing number and null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to build a query which will return only the **phase_ids** that contain **level_id** values of BOTH **numeric** AND **null**

In the following example I would expect to return phase_id 1,3

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(phase_id   numeric(10,0)   null,
 type_id    numeric(10,0)   null,
 level_id   numeric(10,0)   null)

INSERT @tbl VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1,2,1)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1,5,2)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1,1,5)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (1,1,NULL)   
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2,1,2)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2,3,6)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (2,1,1)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (3,1,6)
INSERT @tbl VALUES (3,1,NULL)

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Thank you

Comment: What query you try before ?

Comment: I tried HAVING COUNT but I do not know how to distinguish between the level_id number or nulls

Comment: Add `INSERT @tbl VALUES (4,1,NULL)` to the sample table data, and perhaps adjust the expected result.

Comment: Really, you have to go to the effort of trying to write some kind of query yourself.

Comment: One answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count(*)` counts all rows, `count(level_id)` counts non-null rows:

```
select phase_id
from tbl
group by phase_id
having count(*) <> count(level_id)
   and count(level_id) > 0
```